# How to insert alt tag for fancy box images [ fancyBox3 ]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, fancybox

We are using  http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/  . And this fancybox is working good , except this is not showing img alt tag by default . Even in the documentation also it is not correctly described http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/docs/ .

This is our html structure , in this we are mentioning alt tag both in a , and img . But nothing seems to work .

```
<a data-fancybox="gallery" class="img-1" data-caption="First img" href="img.jpg" data-alt="first img"  data-options='{"alt" : "First img"}'><img src="img.jpg"  alt="First img" class="gallery-fac"></a>

<a data-fancybox="gallery" class="img-2" data-caption="second img" href="img-2.jpg" data-alt="second img"  data-options='{"alt" : "Second img"}'><img src="img-2.jpg"  alt="second img" class="gallery-fac"></a>

$("[data-fancybox]").fancybox({
            thumbs : {
                autoStart : true
            },

 });
```

We found one solution

```
 beforeShow : function() {
        var alt = this.element.find('img').attr('alt');

        this.inner.find('img').attr('alt', alt);

       }
```

But this solution is not working ,So we are searching for solution and got some but that are old .

So if anyone know how to do it , please help to solve.

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1509902, https://www.drupal.org/node/2463287

Comment: this two are old , and it is not working here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `afterLoad` callback to get clicked element (`current.opts.$orig`). Then get value for `alt` attribute (in this sample, I am getting from thumbnail image) and set for the image:

```
$('[data-fancybox="images"]').fancybox({ 
  afterLoad : function(instance, current) {
    current.$image.attr('alt', current.opts.$orig.find('img').attr('alt') );
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOBgqz?editors=1010

btw, is this really important for you? If image does not get loaded, then error message will be displayed and user will not see this alternative text anyway.

Comment: thank you .This is working perfectly and saved my time . But how you know about this ?

Comment: great !!!  :) . Really thank you for quick response . This fancy box is awesome  . Really thanks for all of this . For seo purpose i want to insert alt tag . It's better if you write this in documentation .

Comment: Hi Janis, when I use your script I have current.$image undefined. I have to add setTimeout for it to work. I don't know why. If you have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Adding afterLoad event worked for me, but only like that:

```
afterLoad: function (instance, current) {
      current.$image.attr("alt", $(current.opts.$orig[0]).prop("alt"));
    },
```